# Tensorflow Error with Model.Fit: [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]

Tags: python, numpy, csv, tensorflow, dataset

I have an issue with Tensorflows Model.Fit. I searched the internet, and there are some suggestions, that my problem depends on the latest version of TF. I hope that someone of you can help me fix this or workaround this error.

The Error-Code is:

```
BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence
 [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
```

It occurs in each epoch. I think that my model is correct so far, but the accurancy is about 1.28%, and the loss about -1600. That can´t be true.

I used the "Load CSV data"-tutorial from Tensorflow.org . [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv)

I will put all my code here, it´s about 150 lines. I hope someone can help fix this issue.

Thank you very much in adavance!

Kind regards
Christian Richter

**My code:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import functools

import tensorflow as tf

import xlrd

import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
import csv

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

train_data_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mug8rjlniftu065/train_data_csv.csv?dl=0"

test_data_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/std8rt6lezl79ti/test_data_csv.csv?dl=0"

train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train_data_csv.csv", train_data_url)
test_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("test_data_csv.csv", test_data_url)

np.set_printoptions(precision = 3, suppress=True)

#!head {train_file_path}

Label_Column = 'Besucher'
Labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    './Data/train_data_csv.csv',
    batch_size = 52609,
    select_columns = ['Datum','Uhrzeit','Wochentag','Wochenende','Ferien','Feiertag','Brueckentag','Schneechaos','Streik','Besucher'],
    label_name = 'Besucher',
    num_epochs = 1,
    shuffle = False)



test_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    './Data/alt_test_data_csv.csv',
    batch_size = 1,
    select_columns = ['Datum','Uhrzeit','Wochentag','Wochenende','Feiertag','Besucher'],
    label_name = 'Besucher',
    num_epochs = 1 ,
    shuffle = False)


def show_batch(dataset):
  for batch, label in dataset.take(1):
    for key, value in batch.items():
      print("{:20s}: {}".format(key,value.numpy()))




show_batch(train_dataset)

def pack(features, label):
    return tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis = -1), label

packed_dataset1 = train_dataset.map(pack)
#packed_dataset2 = test_dataset.map(pack)

for features, labels in packed_dataset1.take(1):
    print(features.numpy())
    print()
    print(labels.numpy())

example_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(train_dataset))


class PackNumericFeatures(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names

    def __call__(self, features, labels):

        numeric_features = [features.pop(name) for name in self.names]
        numeric_features = [tf. cast(feat, tf.float32) for feat in numeric_features]
        numeric_features = tf.stack(numeric_features, axis = -1)
        features['numeric'] = numeric_features

        return features, labels

NUMERIC_FEATURES = ['Datum','Uhrzeit','Wochentag','Wochenende','Ferien','Feiertag','Brueckentag','Schneechaos','Streik']

packed_train_data = train_dataset.map(
    PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES)
)
packed_test_data = train_dataset.map(
    PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES)
)

show_batch(packed_train_data)

example_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(packed_train_data))


desc = pd.read_csv("./Data/train_data_csv.csv")[NUMERIC_FEATURES].describe()
desc

MEAN = np.array(desc.T['mean'])
STD = np.array(desc.T['std'])

def normalize_numeric_data(data, mean, std):

    return(data-mean)/std

normalizer = functools.partial(normalize_numeric_data, mean = MEAN, std = STD)

numeric_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('numeric', normalizer_fn=normalizer, shape=[len(NUMERIC_FEATURES)])
numeric_columns = [numeric_column]
numeric_column

example_batch['numeric']

numeric_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(numeric_columns)
numeric_layer(example_batch).numpy()

preprocessing_layer = numeric_layer

print(preprocessing_layer(example_batch).numpy()[0])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    preprocessing_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

train_data = packed_train_data.shuffle(500)
test_data = packed_test_data

model.fit(train_data, epochs = 20)

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_data)

print('\n\nTest Loss {}, Test Accuracy{}'.format(test_loss, test_accuracy))
```

Comment: Can you explain why training data is a part of packed_train_data and not a batch_iterator?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used this method because the tutorial worked this way. They are mapping the training-data with the numeric features, declared before to create the packed_train_data.

Comment: Hi @christianri, Can you provide a new link for your dataset? the train_csv can't be downloaded anymore.

Comment: @christianri, Is your issue resolved now ? Else, can you share link to `train_csv` as it is not available for download, so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @all Thank you all very much for your help! When I wrote the code I had time pressure so I used a different framework to work around my problem. 
So I solved my problem but on a different way. 
But I‘m really glad that there is now a fix for the problem I mentioned in the beginning (as far as I know). 

Thank you very much! Stay as you are, this community is great! 

I will give you the files if wanted to check and reproduce my case. I just want to let you know that I‘m quiet busy right now but I will do as soon as I can!